# android how to convert the json object to json array

Tags: java, android, json

i'm trying to create an application about convert the json object to json array. If it's possible means tell me the way, otherwise, tell the alternate way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
JSONArray jArrayObject = new JSONArray();
jArrayObject.put(getJsonObject());

private static JSONObject getJsonObject() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    //put value jObject here..
}
```